# How to get a specific defendent dropdown list to a specific item

Tags: excel, excel-formula

In list sheet, I have raw data as below

```
Code     Packaging_Options
-----------------------------
HP_PK    FOIL SMALL 10 G 
HP_PK    FOIL SMALL 1.000 S
```

In DataEntry sheet, when I choose HP_PK, the packaging packaging option should generate 2 dropdown options (FOIL SMALL 10 G, FOIL SMALL 1.000 S), but it only generate 1 packaging option.

I am using this formula, but it only returns a single packaging option. Can you help me with the formula?

```
=INDEX(List!$C:$C,MATCH(A12,List!$D:$D,0))
```

Comment: `MATCH()` function finds only the first occurrence hence the `INDEX()` returns only one value, you need to use `FILTER()` if you have it else use `INDEX()`+`AGGREGATE()` here is a reference, a similar query, with a working solution posted. **[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76677791/8162520)**

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Excel Drop Down List for Specific BRAND, BRAND MODEL, BRAND MODEL DESCRIPTION](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76677653/excel-drop-down-list-for-specific-brand-brand-model-brand-model-description)